# Function for tap on showsUserLocation-dot

Tags: swift, mapkit

In a map I show the user location like this:

```
map.showsUserLocation = true
```

I want to do something if the user taps on the dot. Are there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using `MapKit`, in your `MKMapViewDelegate` methods you can react to a user tapping on `MKAnnotationView`s.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
  if let userLocation = view.annotation as? MKUserLocation {
    print("The user tapped on their user location annotation")
  } else {
    print("This is not the user location")
  }
}
```